# Log File Depending on Property Selected in Class Attribute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, serilog, dryioc

I want to create a per file logger which will log to files depending on type and the specifications of an attribute on that type, but I'm having difficulty doing it in a trivial manner.

So I would enumerate through all types using a LogOutputAttribute

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class LogOutputAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string[] Directories { get; set; }

    public LogOutputAttribute(params string[] directories)
    {
        Directories = directories;
    }

    public string ResolveOnMember { get; set; }
}
```

Which is used as such:

```
[LogOutput("Logging", "Subjects", ResolveOnMember = nameof(Name))]
public class LogSubject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in my logger creation:

```
var dirs = new string[] { Path.GetDirectoryName("Logging") };
var logFileName = "Main";

var config = new LoggerConfiguration();

foreach (var type in types)
{
    if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LogOutputAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() is LogOutputAttribute logOutput)
    {
        dirs = logOutput.Directories;
        logFileName = logOutput.ResolveOnMember;
    }

    var path = Path.Combine(dirs);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    Console.WriteLine("Writing to " + path);

    config = config.WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource(type.FullName))
        .WriteTo.Map(logFileName, "unknown", (n, wt) =>
        {
            path = Path.Combine(path, n + ".txt");
            wt.File(path, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day);
        }));
}

var logger = config.CreateLogger();
```

I'd like to enrich the message with the property name and value chosen by the attribute **ResolveOnMember** when the log comes through so it would be processed by the mapping in **.Map**, not sure how or if it's possible to do this.

Another way would be using **ForContext** using **contextual DI injection**,
I use Dryioc which would look like

```
container.Register<Logging.ILogger>(
    made: Made.Of(() => LoggerFactory.GetLogger(new LogContext("SourceContext", Arg.Index<Type>(0))), r => r.Parent.ImplementationType),
    setup: Setup.With(condition: r => r.Parent.ImplementationType != null));
```

But I can't see how to insert the value the chosen **ResolveOnMember** from here.

Comment: Hard to tell, may be registering your LogSubjects into container, maybe with service key or and metadata. Them you may inject and Then you need

Comment: .. sorry, then you may  inject logsubject(s) into logger.